# Import typechain instances from `typechain-truffle` folder

Tags: typescript, types, solidity, typechain

I have a [repo](https://github.com/kuco23/address-from-public-key-in-solidity) for a typechain project and need to do

```js
import { PublicKeyToAddressInstance } from "../typechain-truffle/contracts/PublicKeyToAddress";
```

[here](https://github.com/kuco23/address-from-public-key-in-solidity/blob/master/test/publicKeyToAddress.test.ts#LL2C1-L2C96) to import the type definitions. I've seen it is usually done as

```js
import { PublicKeyToAddressInstance } from "../typechain-truffle";
```

This works for me, but the type for contract methods is always `any`.